# Moving Linux installation from HDD to SSD that already has Windows 10 installed

Tags: partition, grub2, dual-boot, hard-disk, ssd

I have two drives in my laptop:

SSD (128GB):

- Windows 10 installed

HDD (1TB):

- Windows 10 Data
- Linux Mint installed on ext4

Now, once you go SSD you never look back, so loading times on Linux Mint installation are driving me nuts.

From what I’ve read, I could possibly clone the ext4 partition with Clonezilla and move it to a new ext4 partition on SSD. Is that something feasible? I wonder about how grub will behave after the move. I am not very savvy with it and worried that any automated tool I could use after moving Mint partition to SSD is not gonna help me out much.

Any help/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the drive that you're moving to [MBR or GPT](https://www.howtogeek.com/245610/how-to-check-if-a-disk-uses-gpt-or-mbr-and-how-to-convert-between-the-two/)?

Comment: It's MBR from what I've checked.

Comment: See my answer below. My original answer said to use 'disk to disk', but you need to make sure to use 'partition to partition' in clonezilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your Linux install partition with Clonezilla is definitely feasible, and it's probably the easiest way. Here's the general process:

1. Backup any important data. (Although I've successfully done this before, I haven't tested these instructions, so move forward without backup at your own risk).
2. [Shrink your Windows partition](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_WINUI) to provide enough space for your Linux partition, plus a bit more (maybe ~1GB) for the fact that Clonezilla can't clone to a smaller drive than the original.
3. Use a partitioning program ([GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) would be suitable). Create a new partition in the space that you made in step 2.
4. Boot into Clonezilla and do a [disk to disk clone](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone), from your original partition to your new one. **Instead of choosing `disk_to_local_disk` in those instructions, choose, `part_to_local_part`, and select the *partitions* to clone rather than disks to clone.**
5. [Install and configure GRUB on the new drive](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/reinstall-grub-ubuntu-wont-boot/).